# Ionic 3: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I want to display FCM push notification to homepage in a form of loop.
However, I received this error

> HomePage.html:18 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed(…)

I am sorry.. stil new in Ionic 3 (and typescript), anyway thank you in advance

Here's my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
      // Receiving token from FCM
      FCMPlugin.getToken(
        (t) => {
          console.log(t);
        },
        (e) => {
          console.log(e);
        }
      );

      // Receiving notification when app is in background
      FCMPlugin.onNotification(
        (infos) => {
          this.dataProvider.fcmPassing(infos);
          console.log(infos);

          // Display notification when app on foreground
          let basicAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: infos.title,
            subTitle: infos.body,
            buttons: ['OK']
          });
          basicAlert.present();
          },
        (e) => {
          console.log(e);
        }
      );
```

**data.ts**

```
  // Calling FCM data
  fcmReceiving() {
    return this.storage.get('fcmData');
  }  

  // Saving FCM data
  fcmPassing(infos) {
    this.storage.set('fcmData', infos);
  }
```

**home.ts**

```
 infos: Promise<any>;
 public notis = [];

 // Calling FCM data via DataProvider
this.dataProvider.fcmReceiving()
.then((info) => {
  console.log('fcm data', info);
  this.infos = info.title;
  this.notis = info;
})
```

**home.html**

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let noti of notis" (click)="passingFCM(infos)">Hello {{noti.title}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: Show us how `notis` looks like, what error is saying is that you are trying to loop over object

Comment: @mxr7350 notis is an empty array.. If then, how can I loop an object?

Comment: No it isn't, unless `info` is too (`this.notis = info;`) which is unlikely since it has a property. You can't loop over an object; it doesn't make any sense. `{{noti.title}}` should print the title if you just remove the loop altogether.

Comment: You declared `notis` to be empty array, but than in the `fcmReceiving()` you are setting it to `info` which is by error Implication Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented that notis is an array, but you imply in your code example that the retrieved *info* is an object:

```
console.log('fcm data', info);
this.infos = info.title;
this.notis = info;
```

In this case, this.notis is not an array. It is whatever info is, which in your case is not an array as it contains other data, like **info.title**

set this.notis to the array within info